# How get previous page url after redirect from another site?

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the redirected site url? I am just curious about how to get the code of `TinyUrl`. Suppose I have created an url on tinyurl like `http://ty.com/abcdef` and this is to be redirected to my site like `http://example.com/some-another-url` . How do I get the code of `tinyurl` from `http://example.com/some-another-url` ?

** ty.com for tinyurl.com

Comment: You can look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it can't be considered reliable.

Comment: @Jon I have already tried that but that is not working..  :(

Comment: there is no reverse mapping of url shorteners if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

PS: **This is unreliable as it may not work with secure pages (HTTPS)**